# Why does TypeError shows in my elif statement

Tags: python, discord

I am working on discord hacking tool with 16 options. I started working on a Delete Discord Servers option and i have in elif statement error. I tried everything what i knew and it didnt changed. If anyone can to help me with this i would be grateful to him.

My Login Function :

```
def login(token):
    data = {}
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        try:
            os.system(f'title 8300 │ Authenticated: {client.user.name}#{client.user.discriminator}')
            RPC.close()
            RPC.connect()
            RPC.update(state=f'Authorized Token: {client.user.name}#{client.user.discriminator}', details='Awaiting Nuke Option', large_image='8300',small_image="8300",large_text="discord.gg/83",small_text="8300")
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

My Delete Servers Function:

```py
def deleteg(guild, token):
    re = requests.delete(f'https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/{guild}', headers={"Authorization": token})
    if re.status_code == 200 or re.status_code == 201 or re.status_code == 204:
        print(f"{r}[{g}STATUS{r}] {g}Deleted {r}>> [ {g}{guild} {r}]")
    elif re.status_code == 429:
        print(f"{r}[{g}STATUS{r}] {g}Failed Delete {r}>> [ {g}{guild} {r}]")
        time.sleep(re.json()['retry_after'])
```

My statement:

```
   elif opcija == 2:
        clear()
        token = input("Enter a token of the user: ")
        acc = login(token)
        for guild in acc['guildsID']:
            threading.Thread(target=deleteG(), args=(guild,token,))
```

My Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OVDE KLIK\Documents\Projekat\main.py", line 191, in <module>
    dizajn()
  File "C:\Users\OVDE KLIK\Documents\Projekat\main.py", line 187, in dizajn
    for guild in acc['guildsID']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `login()` never returns anything, so `acc is None`

Comment: What should i add to login fonctuion to acc return something?

Comment: Presumably, RPC has a a method to pull the data out, no?

Comment: Yes, it has. What i need to do with this RPC ?